# How do I create custom unmarshallers to process parameter lists using akka-http?

Tags: scala, unmarshalling, akka-http

I'm trying to unmarshal parameters from an input sent to my route so that the route is able to deal with the parameters and send back a BadRequest if the parameters are not correctly formatted. The specific parameter I am looking at parsing is an orderBy request used in a REST-ful application.

I was thinking of structuring the request by having multiple fields coupled with a sorting integer. The field and integer are separated by a `:` whereas the field-integer combinations are comma separated.

An example of this request would look like this: `/path?orderBy=id:-1,name:1`

I would like to create a custom unmarshaller that is able to turn this parameter list into a `List[(String, Int)]` to send to my query function that will decompose it and use it in the query. Akka-http supports a `CsvList` unmarshaller however this is not adequate for my implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the answer provided by Tim I was able to come up with a slightly different answer. The original answer by Tim has an unnecessary implicit parameter inside the definition which can be removed since this implementation doesn't require an unmarshaller of its own. It is a base unmarshaller.

I did this:

```
implicit val pairSeq = Unmarshaller.strict[String, (String, Int)] { string =>
    val Array(a, b) = string.split(':')
    a -> b.toInt
  }

...

import foo.pairSeq

path("PATH") {
  parameter("orderBy".as(CsvSeq[(String, Int)])) { ob =>
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
implicit def pairSeq(implicit unmarshaller: Unmarshaller[String, (String, Int)]) =
  Unmarshaller.strict[String, (String, Int)] { string =>
    val Array(a, b) = string.split(':')
    a -> b.toInt
  }

...

path("PATH") {
  parameter("orderBy".as(CsvSeq[(String, Int)])) { ob =>
    ...
  }
```

`ob` will be a `List[(String, Int)]` if the parameter is formatted correctly.

This uses a custom marshaller for `(String, Int)` which splits the string at `:` and converts the second value to `Int`. This custom marshaller is used by `CsvSeq` to unpick each comma-separated value in `orderBy`.

Comment: When trying to use multiple optional parameters I get the following error:

```Error:(37, 37) 3 more arguments than can be applied to method parameters: (pdm: akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ParameterDirectives.ParamMagnet)pdm.Out
                     'limit.as[Int].?,```

With the following code:

```parameters('orderBy.as(CsvSeq[(String, Int)]).?,
                     'limit.as[Int].?,
                     'offset.as[Int].?,
                     'fields.as(csvList[String]).?)```

Comment: It is hard to tell if this is related to the custom marshaller. Try to create the simplest version that works without the custom marshaller but fails with the custom marshaller.